# Exception when creating new instance of OkHttp3.OkHttpClient

Tags: java, android, okhttp

I'm trying to use [OkHttp](https://github.com/square/okhttp) to download a file from a webserver in an Android app. After creating a new Project with Android Studio (API level 28) I added a button and am ImageView to my Activity. The idea is to download the an image when I press the button and show it on the screen.

I'm using the latest version of OkHttp, 3.14.0.

I added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` to the AndroidManifest.xml file.

I tried to use the OkHttpClient exactly as described in the [examples](http://square.github.io/okhttp/#examples). This is what my code looks like:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ... // onCreate method

    public void btnClicked(View view) {
        new DownloadImageAsyncTask().execute("https://link.to/image.jpg");
    }

    public class DownloadImageAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        ... // override doInBackground()
    }
}
```

When l run the app and press the button, the `btnClicked()` method is executed and the app crashes. The error occurs when calling `OkHttpClient()` no matter if I place it as a field in the `DownloadImageAsyncTask` class, as a local variable of the `doInBackground()` method or as a field in the `ManActivity` class.

I've also ried to use the Builder (`new OkHttpClient.Builder().build()`) to initialize the object but with the same outcome.

Here's the stack trace:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.myapp.httpstuff, PID: 17796
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:390)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574) 
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
     Caused by: java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: Exception from call site #4 bootstrap method
        at okhttp3.internal.Util.<clinit>(Util.java:87)
        at okhttp3.internal.Util.immutableList(Util.java:234)
        at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.<clinit>(OkHttpClient.java:124)
        at com.myapp.httpstuff.MainActivity$DownloadImageAsyncTask.<init>(MainActivity.java:31)
        at com.myapp.httpstuff.MainActivity.btnClicked(MainActivity.java:26)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574) 
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: Bootstrap method returned null
        at okhttp3.internal.Util.<clinit>(Util.java:87) 
        at okhttp3.internal.Util.immutableList(Util.java:234) 
        at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.<clinit>(OkHttpClient.java:124) 
        at com.myapp.httpstuff.MainActivity$DownloadImageAsyncTask.<init>(MainActivity.java:31) 
        at com.myapp.httpstuff.MainActivity.btnClicked(MainActivity.java:26) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574) 
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OkHttp 3.13+ requires Java 8+ or Android 5+. I think you've encountered a situation where a Java 8 lambda is not expected by the ART runtime.

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/art/+/master/runtime/interpreter/interpreter_common.cc#1399

```
Handle<mirror::Object> object(hs.NewHandle(result.GetL()));
if (UNLIKELY(object.IsNull())) {
  // This will typically be for LambdaMetafactory which is not supported.
  ThrowClassCastException("Bootstrap method returned null");
  return nullptr;
}
```

You'll probably have success updating your build.gradle.

```
android { 
  compileOptions { 
    targetCompatibility = "8"
    sourceCompatibility = "8"
   }
 }
```

https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/4597

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this solved my issue! But I actually had to execute the _clean project_ command before the changes in the build.gradle file were applied.

Comment: i am getting error could not initialize class okhttp3.OkHttpClient . It is a maven project

Answer (score 3):

After trying everythin that came to my mind I tried using an older version of OkHttp.

Using `OkHttp:2.7.2` instead, my code works as expected.

I just tested `Okhttp3:3.12.2` as well and this fixes the issue as well.

Interestingly `OkHttp3:3.12.2` was released a day after `OkHttp3:3.14.0` (https://github.com/square/okhttp/releases)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer why it works with the `Okhttp3:3.12.2`:

> Google’s distribution dashboard shows that ~11% of the devices that visited the Play Store in October 2018 were running Android 4.x. We’ve created a branch, OkHttp 3.12.x, to support these devices. Should we encounter any severe bugs or security problems we’ll backport the fixes and release. We plan to maintain this branch through December 31, 2020.

Source: https://medium.com/square-corner-blog/okhttp-3-13-requires-android-5-818bb78d07ce